# Gmail filter to apply to specific "Label"

Tags: gmail-filters

Can I set a Filter so that when I apply a specific label to an email in the Inbox it is forwarded to another email address? Example: If I label an email "Important",can a filter also forward it to a another inbox?

Answer (score 1):

Filters can do multiple actions at once so, yes, you could create a filter that marks certain messages "Important" *and* forwards to a specified address.

However, filters only act on messages as they are received. You can't manually add a label/status and have a filter pick up on that to send the message.